# Basic architecture guideline for web based project : cloud

Tags: java, mysql, web-applications, jsp-tags

We are doing small database maintenance work to earn some money. A new client asked if we can develop a shopping website to list items to sell and buy.  This is to cater 300K users,(around 20K users online at  same time ).  Each user has custom home page, saved setting for shopping carts, items to sell,  basic reports (earning etc).

we prefer Java as development language and mysql as database.

What kind of ready to use tools available for presentation layer?   Is there is could solutions providing necessary services?

Comment: The users will spend nearly 7% of their total life on a single shopping site? That's gotta be a pretty compelling site...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Apache Click, seems to have a simple presentation layer. Don't know about ORMs much.